# How to Create Custom Page in admin site with list filter - Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I am new to Django, let say I have a page which displays `car brands` in the admin panel. Now I would like to add a `new custom page` in admin site which displays all cars based on the `brand name` like image . how can I achieve this?

[image]

My Brand and Cars Admin Looks Like follow

```
class BrandAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['title', 'created', 'owner', 'cars_count','is_active']
actions = [ 'deactivate', 'activate' ]


"""
returns new url for admin site
"""
def get_urls(self):
    admin_urls = super(BrandAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = [
        url(r'^(?P<Brand_id>[0-9]+)/detail/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(BrandDetail.as_view()), name="admin_Brand_detail"),
        url(r'^(?P<Brand_id>[0-9]+)/cars/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(carsListView.as_view()), name="admin_Brand_cars_list")
    ]
    return my_urls + admin_urls

admin.site.register(Brand, BrandAdmin)





class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['name', 'stage', 'modal']
list_filter = ['brand', 'stage']

admin.site.register(Car, CarAdmin)
```

In the `get_urls` in `BrandAdmin` class i have added the urls for new admin page.

My ques:
I want to add the new link field in the Brand Admin Table which redirects to the new admin page where i want to display all the cars based on `Brand` like in image i have attached.

Comment: Can you provide your code for your `car brands` page you're talking about ? because you only showed the default `Users` page.

Comment: first of all you need to make you model modifiable in the admin site(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin) second you need overwrite the method get_queryset(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) and of course make you query for to get what you are looking for

Comment: @scharette i attached sample image, now I have edited my question.

Comment: @Reidel I have already registered the `car` and `brand` in admin site which has the separate view to display all the `car` and `brand`. now I want to add a link to the brand admin table which redirects to the new custom admin page which displays all cars with filter, action, a table like normal image i have attached.

Comment: If you want the link in the initial page of django admin you can override this template `admin/index.html` as you can read here an example of override the `base_site.html` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial07/#customize-the-admin-look-and-feel

Comment: My another doubt is lets say, For end users i have view called `CarsBasedonBrandView(ListView)` which takes `brand_id` as pk.which display all the cars using `jquerydatatable`,what should i do if i want same view to admin page but this time i want to use `list filter (default table given for django admin )`, should i write separate view or same different templates.

Comment: you can put a link in the overridden template that I told you `index.html` and address it to the view you want, even you can use the header of the admin site in you the template `CarsBasedonBrandView(ListView)` but I don't know if you can use the `list filter (default table given for django admin )`, you need to try it